# How does OS execute binary files in virtual memory?

Tags: c, assembly

For example in my program I called a function foo(). The compiler and assembler would eventually write `jmp someaddr` in the binary. I know the concept of virtual memory. The program would think that it has the whole memory at disposal, and the start position is `0x000`. In this way the assembler can calculate the position of foo().

But in fact this is not decided until runtime right? I have to run the program to know where I loaded the program into, hence the address of the `jmp`. But when the program actually runs, how does the OS come in and change the address of the `jmp`? These are direct CPU instructions right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit

Comment: Do you understand the concept of "jump relative to"...

Comment: This sounds like an OS design question, not a programming question. The answer is that since the address space is virtual, the program gets loaded exactly where it wants, as far as it can tell. That's the magic of virtual addressing

Comment: Virtual addresses are transparent to the application. The physical address is only known to the CPU by consulting the page tables; the application never knows its location in physical memory (which may vary anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question can't be answered in general because it's totally hardware and OS dependent.  However a typical answer is that the initially loaded program can be compiled as you say: Because the VM hardware gives each program its own address space, all addresses can be fixed when the program is linked.  No recalculation of addresses at load time is needed.

Things get much more interesting with dynamically loaded libraries because two used by the same initially loaded program might be compiled with the same base address, so their address spaces overlap.

One approach to this problem is to require Position Independent Code in DLLs.  In such code all addresses are relative to the code itself. Jumps are usually relative to the PC (though a code segment register can also be used).  Data are also relative to some data segment or base register.  To choose the runtime location, the PIC code itself needs no change.  Only the segment or base register(s) need(s) be set whenever in the prelude of every DLL routine.

PIC tends to be a bit slower than position dependent code because there's additional address arithmetic and the PC and/or base registers can bottleneck the processor's instruction pipeline.

So the other approach is for the loader to rebase the DLL code when necessary to eliminate address space overlaps. For this the DLL must include a table of all the absolute addresses in the code.  The loader computes an offset between the assumed code and data base addresses and actual, then traverses the table, adding the offset to each absolute address as the program is copied into VM.

DLLs also have a table of entry points so that the calling program knows where the library procedures start.  These must be adjusted as well.

Rebasing is not great for performance either.  It slows down loading.  Moreover, it defeats sharing of DLL code.  You need at least one copy per rebase offset.

For these reasons, DLLs that are part of Windows are deliberately compiled with non-overlapping VM address spaces.  This speeds loading and allows sharing.  If you ever notice that a 3rd party DLL crunches the disk and loads slowly, while MS DLLs like the C runtime library load quickly, you are seeing the effects of rebasing in Windows.

You can infer more about this topic by reading about object file formats.  [Here is one example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

Answer (score 2):

**Position-independent code** is code that you can run from any address.  If you have a `jmp` instruction in position-independent code, it will often be a relative jump, which jumps to an offset from the current location.  When you copy the code, it won't change the offsets between parts of the code so it will still work.

**Relocatable code** is code that you can run from any address, but you might have to modify the code first (maybe you can't just copy it).  The code will contain a relocation table which tells how it needs to be modified.

**Non-relocatable code** is code that must be loaded at a certain address or it will not work.

Each program is different, it depends on how the program was written, or the compiler settings, or other various factors.

- Shared libraries are usually compiled as position-independent code, which allows the same library to be loaded at different locations in different processes, without having to load multiple copies into memory.  The same copy can be shared between processes, even though it is at a different address in each process.
- Executables are often non-relocatable, but they can be position-independent.  Virtual memory allows each program to have the entire address space (minus some overhead) to itself, so each executable can choose the address at which it's loaded without worrying about collisions with other executables.  Some executables are position-independent, which can be used to increase security (ASLR).
- Object files and static libraries are usually relocatable code.  The linker will relocate them when combining them to create a shared library, executable, or other image.
- Boot loaders and operating system kernels are almost always non-relocatable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is at runtime.  The operating system, the part managing starting and switching tasks is ideally at a different protection level, it has more power.  It knows what memory is in use and allocates some for the new task.  It configures the mmu so that the new task has a virtual address space starting at zero or whatever the rule is for that operating system and processor.  How you get into user mode at that starting address, is very processor specific.

One method for example is the hardware might save some state not just address but mode or virtual id or something when an interrupt occurs, lets say on the stack.  And the return from interrupt instruction as defined by that processor takes the address, and state/mode, off of the stack and switches there (causing lets assume the mmu to react to its next fetch based on the new mode not the old).  For a processor that works like that then you may be able to fake an interrupt return by placing the right items on the stack such that when you kick the interrupt return instruction it basically does a jump with additional features of mode switching, etc.

The ARM family for example (not cortex-m) has a processor state register for what you are running now (in the case of an interrupt or service call) and a second state register for where you came from, the state that was interrupted, when you do the proper return you give it the address and it switches back to that mode using the other register.  You can directly access that register from the non-users modes so you can manipulate the state of the return.  There is no return instruction in arm, just flavors of jump (modifications to the program counter), so it is a special kind of jump.

The short answer is that it is very specific to the processor as to what your choices are for jumping to the first time or returning to after a task switch to a running task in an application mode in a virtual address space.  Either directly or indirectly the processor documentation will describe these modes and how you change them.  If not explicitly described then you have to figure out on your own from the instructions and the mmu protections and such how to switch tasks.